# Which is the most idiomatic way to "lift up" by some transformation both arguments of a binary function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, applicative, arrows

Which is the most idiomatic way to "lift up" by some transformation both arguments of a binary function in Haskell? Let this operator be named "lift", so I expect it's type will be

```
lift :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> a -> c)
```

and a naive definition will be

```
lift t f = \x y -> f (t x) (t y)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) (from `Data.Function`), although with flipped arguments:

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
-- lift = flip on
```

Note that you could have found the function easily with a [Hoogλe](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%28b%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c%29%20-%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20c%29) query. Also note that there's already a function `lift`, which is used in a completely other setting, namely monad transformers.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the fast answer and the link to hoogle especially!

Comment: @ramntry: You might want to look at the [haskell tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info), it contains some good resources.